# html/jquery input type: text within radio not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[name$='why']").hide();
 $("label input[type='radio']").change(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('more')) $(this).next().show();
  else $(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();
  if ($(this).hasClass('mor')) $(this).next().show();
  else $(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();

  });
   $("label input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('more')) {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    }
     });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form>
 <label for="Q01">
    Question 1:<br/>
 <input name="Q01" id="Q1_A02" type="radio" value="Q1_A02" class="more" />No, why?
    <input class="more" name="why" id="Q1_A03" type="text" value="" /><br />
 <input name="Q01" id="Q1_A04" type="radio" value="Q1_A04" class="mor"/>yes, why?
    <input name="why" id="Q1_A05" type="text" value="" /><br />

</label>
```

I  have been trying to made a form that when radio button no is clicked it will show the text field and when yes is clicked no text will disappear and yes text will show,but not working ?

**The form code :**

```
 <form>
 <label for="Q01">
    Question 1:<br/>
 <input name="Q01" id="Q1_A02" type="radio" value="Q1_A02" class="more" />No, why?
    <input class="more" name="why" id="Q1_A03" type="text" value="" /><br />
 <input name="Q01" id="Q1_A04" type="radio" value="Q1_A04" class="mor"/>yes, why?
    <input name="why" id="Q1_A05" type="text" value="" /><br />

</label>
```

**The jquery code :**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[name$='why']").hide();
 $("label input[type='radio']").change(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('more')) $(this).next().show();
  else $(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();
  if ($(this).hasClass('mor')) $(this).next().show();
  else $(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();

  });
   $("label input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('more')) {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    }
     });
     });
```

Comment: What do you do when it doesn't work? You either fix it or ask for help! you are doing none of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but you may try something like this. First, make sure to hide text fields through css like so..

```
#Q1_A03, #Q1_A05 {
display:none;   
}
```

then..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#Q1_A02').on('click', function(){
    $('#Q1_A03').show();
    $('#Q1_A05').hide();
 });

 $('#Q1_A04').on('click', function(){
    $('#Q1_A05').show();
    $('#Q1_A03').hide();
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hocstvy6/)

I'm sure there may be other more easier ways. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is in your condition, the second `else` is hiding first input.

Change your JavaScript code like this:

```
$(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();
if ($(this).hasClass('more')) $(this).next().show();
if ($(this).hasClass('mor')) $(this).next().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js code should be idented correctly. You have a wrongly nested if statement.

Below the correct nesting:

```
$("input[name$='why']").hide();
$("label input[type='radio']").change(function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass('more')) {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();

        if ($(this).hasClass('mor')) {
            $(this).next().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().children("input[type='text']").hide();
        }
    }
});
$("label input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass('more')) {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1utr2hgg/)

Answer (score 0):

this code will help you

```
$("input[type='text']").hide();
$("input[type='radio']").eq(0).click(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").show();
});
```